# Changing columns to rows with specific Id's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello I'd like to know if I could somehow take single text word from a column and make them a single cell in a row. This is hard to describe but hopefully I can provide a screenshot. 
[image]

So the "Contents" word should be cut out and everything after that should be in their own cells with the id tagged next to the cell. The wordcount in one column can differ from 1 to 100. Same with the ID count.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Between "what I have" and "what I need" should be "what I tried". Any chance you could show us that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should achieve the goal you give:

```
Private Sub SortAndSplit()
Dim docId, docContent, lastRow, docArray, myLoop, myArrayLoop, lastRowList
Dim wSheet: Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = wSheet.Cells(wSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Get last row in column 2 (B)

For myLoop = 2 To lastRow
    docId = wSheet.Range("A" & myLoop).Value
    docContent = wSheet.Range("B" & myLoop).Value
    docArray = Split(Trim(Replace(docContent, "Contents ", "")), ",")
    For myArrayLoop = 0 To UBound(docArray)
        lastRowList = wSheet.Cells(wSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' Get last row in column 4 (D) and add 1
        wSheet.Range("D" & lastRowList).Value = docId
        wSheet.Range("E" & lastRowList).Value = docArray(myArrayLoop)
    Next
Next  
End Sub
```